# Create game inventory system, without casting to derived

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns

I am trying to implement a high-performance game inventory system. I have This abstract base class to store different type of items in Inventory, for example, Coin, Flashlight, Knife etc..

```
public abstract class ObtainableItem 
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ObtainableItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

For example, I have a DoorKey which opens a door. DoorKey has a property KeyCode which will be used for opening a door.

```
public class DoorKey : ObtainableItem
{
    public int KeyCode { get; private set; }

    public DoorKey() : base("key")
    {
        KeyCode = 1234;
    }
}
```

All ObtainableItem are stored in Inventory

```
public class Inventory
{
    const int slotCount = 2;
    ObtainableItem[] slots = new ObtainableItem[slotCount];

    public Inventory()
    {
        slots[0] = new DoorKey();
    }
}
```

Now imagine user drags DoorKey from his Inventory on a Door and triggers Open method

```
public class Door
{
    public void Open(ObtainableItem key)
    {
        if (key is DoorKey)
        {
            DoorKey doorKey = (DoorKey)key;
            if (doorKey.KeyCode == 1234)
            {
                // Open door
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // "can't use this item on a door"
        }
    }
}
```

How to avoid cast from ObtainableItem to a DoorKey? I have read that using casting is bad practice and it points at a bad code oop design. Ideally, a Door class should look like this. Is there any pattern I should for my inventory system?

```
public class Door
{
    public void Open(DoorKey key)
    {
        if (key.KeyCode == 1234)
        {
            // Open door
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you read *casting is bad practice*, I've never read any such thing.

Comment: @ErikPhilips propably refering to the overhead of boxing/unboxing

Comment: @RandRandom yeah, so then it's *boxing/unboxing can cause performance problems* which is significantly different than *bad practice*.

Comment: Note that in the existing code, you can save a cast by using `as` and checking for null, rather than using `is` and then casting again if it returns true.

Comment: This question is way, way too broad.  I can think of like a dozen different awesome design patterns here.

Comment: You should prefer polymorphism to casting. While I wouldn't go so far as to say that _"casting is bad practice"_ -- it is, after all, a necessary evil in some cases -- it most commonly can and should be avoided, and if you find yourself downcasting to a more specific type, that's often an indication that your design is flawed. And yes, the question is way too broad, having many different alternatives that would also work.

Answer (score 1):

There are always exceptions that can be made for ease of implementation and readability.  What you describe is common, if not typical.

An alternative would be to have the "control" logic in the class that calls `Door.Open`.  This could be easily achieved with a touch of reflection:

```
public abstract class ObtainableItem
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ObtainableItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public abstract class WorldItem
{
}

public interface IActsOn<in TWorldItem>
    where TWorldItem : WorldItem
{
    void ApplyTo(TWorldItem worldItem);
}

public class World
{
    // If profiling shows that this is a performance issue, a cache keyed by tWorldItem, tInvItem 
    // should fix it.  No expiry or invalidation should be needed.
    private Action<ObtainableItem, WorldItem> GetApplyTo(Type tWorldItem, Type tInvItem)
    {
        var tActOn = typeof(IActsOn<>).MakeGenericType(tWorldItem);
        if (!tActOn.IsAssignableFrom(tInvItem))
        {
            return null;
        }
        var methodInfo = tActOn.GetMethod(nameof(IActsOn<WorldItem>.ApplyTo));

        return new Action<ObtainableItem, WorldItem>((invItem, worldItem) =>
        {
            methodInfo.Invoke(invItem, new object[] { worldItem });
        });
    }

    public bool IsDropTarget(WorldItem worldItem, ObtainableItem item) 
        => GetApplyTo(worldItem.GetType(), item.GetType()) != null;

    public void ActOn(WorldItem worldItem, ObtainableItem item)
    {
        var actOn = GetApplyTo(worldItem.GetType(), item.GetType());
        if (actOn == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        actOn(item, worldItem);
    }
}
```

While this slightly complicates the implementation of `World`, it simplifies the implementation of various objects:

```
class Door : WorldItem
{
    public void Unlock(string bitting)
    {
        if (bitting == "1234")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Door Opened");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Door could not unlock");
        }
    }
}

class DoorKey : ObtainableItem, IActsOn<Door>
{
    private readonly string Bitting;

    public DoorKey(string bitting)
        : base("Key")
    {
        this.Bitting = bitting;
    }

    public void ApplyTo(Door worldItem)
    {
        worldItem.Unlock(this.Bitting);
    }
}

class RubberChicken : ObtainableItem
{
    public RubberChicken()
        : base("Rubber chicken")
    {
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var key1 = new DoorKey("1234");
        var key2 = new DoorKey("4321");
        var rubberChicken = new RubberChicken();

        var door = new Door();

        var world = new World();
        Debug.Assert(!world.IsDropTarget(door, rubberChicken));
        Debug.Assert(world.IsDropTarget(door, key1));

        world.ActOn(door, key2);
        world.ActOn(door, key1);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```